# What is the order of power intake across a GPU's power connectors?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, circuit-analysis, pcie

On an Nvidia/EVGA 3080/3090 FTW3 GPU, there are three 8-pin PCIe power connectors. How does the "ordering" of power draw work across its 3x power ports (+ its PCIe slot)?

For example, if a 3080 FTW3 suddenly needed 450W of power, how or in what order would that be drawn: would it grab as much power as it can get from one power source before moving onto the next, e.g.:

- 75W from PCIe slot (..75W total)
- -> 150W from 8-pin #1 (..225W total)
- -> 150W from 8-pin #2 (..375W total)
- -> remaining 75W from 8-pin #3 (..450W)

..? Or does the GPU draw power through all the ports in parallel? What happens if one port can't supply power equally as the other two?

As an example: if you have two 8-pin PCIe power cables + one 6-pin -- given 6-pin cables will only have 75W max drawn over them -- what would happen as far as power draw? Would it matter which port the 6-pin cable was plugged into? How would the GPU respond in a case like this, or if the 6-pin cable was alternated between ports 1-3?

Comment: All of the ports (except Pcie) are connected in parralel. There is no need for so many of them - it's just to keep voltage drop across cables/connectors low to minimize power loss. So power over them is distributed as equally as resistance of wires are

Comment: @fifi_22 Are you positive on this? Someone else commented that their PSU has per-port power monitoring and it shows that the ports show different power draws at various times. Not disagreeing with you, just wondering if and why this might be. Perhaps the GPU's logic enables power ports on an as-needed basis, like when clock boosting?